# Sorting a python dictionary of lists by date

Tags: python, list, sorting, date, dictionary

I'm writing a Django project as a student intern. 
I have the following dictionary of list of data in my python file :

```
list_sequences = {'01': [["Calcul Red Shift", "2014-09-24", "Running"]],
                  '02': [["Calcul Dérive", "2014-09-22", "Stopped"]],
                  '03': [["Calcul simple", "2014-04-12", "Paused"]],
                  '04': [["Calcul Mental", "2014-02-14", "Failed"]],
                  '05': [["Sauvegarde des données", "2014-12-22", "Running"]],
                  '06': [["Envoi des données", "2014-07-17", "Stopped"]],
                  '07': [["Calcul de LA question", "2015-01-06", "Running"]],
                  '08': [["Refactorisation", "2014-09-24", "Paused"]],
                  '09': [["Cuisson de choucroute", "2013-11-13", "Running"]],
                  '10': [["Ecriture du rapport", "2014-02-03", "Running"]],
                  '11': [["Nettoyage des fichiers", "2014-09-24", "Paused"]],
                  '12': [["Création des utilisateurs", "2015-01-06", "Failed"]]
}
```

As you can see, the key of each element is 01, 02, ...

I also use double [[ ]] because I use strings and otherwise the webpage shows only one character in the table cells.

What I would like to do is sorting the whole dictionary by date.

I tried the following :

```
list_sequences = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(list_sequences.items(), key=lambda e: e[0][1]))
```

and also this :

```
list_sequences = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(list_sequences.items(), key=lambda e: datetime.datetime.strptime(e[0][1], '%Y-%m-%d')))
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The first one sorts my list in a weird way and the second one throws me a :

```
time data '0' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dict.items()` returns (key, value) pairs, so the value is at index 1(`e[1]`) not 0(`e[0]`). You need to change `e[0][1]` to `e[1][0][1]`.

**Demo:**

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(list_sequences.items(), key=lambda e:datetime.strptime(e[1][0][1], '%Y-%m-%d')))
OrderedDict([('09', [['Cuisson de choucroute', '2013-11-13', 'Running']]), ('10', [['Ecriture du rapport', '2014-02-03', 'Running']]), ('04', [['Calcul Mental', '2014-02-14', 'Failed']]), ('03', [['Calcul simple', '2014-04-12', 'Paused']]), ('06', [['Envoi des donn\xc3\xa9es', '2014-07-17', 'Stopped']]), ('02', [['Calcul D\xc3\xa9rive', '2014-09-22', 'Stopped']]), ('11', [['Nettoyage des fichiers', '2014-09-24', 'Paused']]), ('01', [['Calcul Red Shift', '2014-09-24', 'Running']]), ('08', [['Refactorisation', '2014-09-24', 'Paused']]), ('05', [['Sauvegarde des donn\xc3\xa9es', '2014-12-22', 'Running']]), ('12', [['Cr\xc3\xa9ation des utilisateurs', '2015-01-06', 'Failed']]), ('07', [['Calcul de LA question', '2015-01-06', 'Running']])])
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you !
I've added a "reverted" method so that the most recent date comes first : 

    list_sequences = collections.OrderedDict(reversed(sorted(list_sequences.items(), key=lambda e: e[1][0][1])))

Comment: @Frankynov You can simply pass `reverse=True` to `sorted()` function itself.